# c#, eager loading collection of collection with Nhibernate (QueryOver or Linq) return "cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags"

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, collections, queryover

i read tons of answer about this but don't find a way to apply to my specific case

i simply have `User` object which have `ICollection<Group> Groups` property and each Group have a "ICollection Roles' proeprty

now i have to eager load a specific user with Groups filled and Roles of each group filled to

i try (among many other) this 3 way:

1:

```
 _session.Query<User>().FetchMany(u => u.Groups).ThenFetchMany(g => g.Roles)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

2:

```
var utente = _session.QueryOver<User>()
.Fetch(x => x.Groups).Eager
.Fetch(x => x.Groups.First().Roles).Eager
.Where(x => x.IdUtente == idUtente)
.SingleOrDefault();
```

3:

```
 var query = _session.QueryOver<Utente>()
    .Where(u => u.IdUtente == idUtente)
    .Future();

Gruppo gruppi = null;
Ruolo ruolo = null;
_session.QueryOver<Utente>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(u => u.Gruppi, () => gruppi)
    .Left.JoinAlias(() => gruppi.Ruoli, () => ruolo)
    .Future();

return query.ToList().First();
```

but every time i get: `cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it setting `.AsSet` on collection proeprty in nhibernate maps